# Pandas read csv skipping # character

Tags: pandas

I want to read the following file "test.csv" in Pandas:

```
# TEXT 1
# TEXT 2
# STN,YYYYMMDD,   HH,   DD,   FH,   FF,   FX
# 
  225,19900101,    1,  110,   36,   41,   46
  225,19900101,    2,   90,   36,   36,   51
  225,19900101,    3,  120,   31,   31,   46
```

In the csv I want to skip all lines that start with # and I want to use the third line as headers (column names), without having the #-character in the header.

What works is: :

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=2)
df = df.iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)
df.rename(columns={"# STN": "STN"},inplace=True)
```

Which gives:

```
      STN    YYYYMMDD     HH     DD     FH     FF     FX
0     225  19900101.0    1.0  110.0   36.0   41.0     46
1     225  19900101.0    2.0   90.0   36.0   36.0     51
2     225  19900101.0    3.0  120.0   31.0   31.0     46
```

But I wonder if there is a way from import to skip this #-character as lines, and get the headers without the #-character (so I don't have to manually find on which lines I have to skip and where to find the headers)?

Comment: There is a comments option in pandas read csv ... pd.read_csv(filename,comments=#,header=0,...) it will skip those lines and pick the next line without # as the header

Comment: The comment=# works, but in this case I have to uncomment the headers. Otherwise they are also removed

Comment: i think u r better off reading it via python's csv, where u can have more granular control. I was able to work it out that way. my 2 cents